# Getting View data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hy Guys!

I don't know how to get this data on my controller. could somebody help me?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Pedido</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Assunto)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Assunto)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Assunto)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Data)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Data)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Data)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

Tks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make an overload of the action method that takes the model as a parameter.
MVC will do the rest.

Comment: And add the HttpPost attribute to the method.